# Importing file metadata to spreadsheet

Tags: windows, file, attributes, spreadsheet

Looking to create a spreadsheet of all the file data from a folder of files in Windows 10.

Specifically for this example, the "length" of a group of audio files is desired.

All the methods readily available online, such as "copying file path" or opening the folder in a web browser and copy/pasting the data into a new spreadsheet, seem to allow only for a select few attributes to be captured.  Namely, file path, size, and date created.

How can one export other, less common, attributes into spreadsheet form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a simple answer.

Managed to import the file size using a macro.

From there, used a spreadsheet formula to calculate the length of the audio based on the bitrate.